# How to use filter in react?

Tags: reactjs, ethereum

I am building check-in app by using ethereum and react.

`checkin` have `placeid` and `username`, and I want to filter the array by id.

Now, my code is like this

```
{ this.props.checkins.map((checkin, key) => {
  return(
    <div key={key}>
      <p>ID{checkin.placeid}, Address:{checkin.username}</p>
    </div>
  )
})}
```

Could you give me any advise, please.

Comment: No special magic required, just the plain old array `filter` method.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using [.filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp) you can filter your array based on a condition, the function returns an array of items that satisfy the condition.

> The **filter()** method creates an array filled with all array elements that pass a test (provided as a function).

```
const filtered = this.props.checkins.filter(item => item.placeid === someid);

{ filtered.map((checkin, key) => {
  return(
    <div key={key}>
      <p>ID{checkin.placeid}, Address:{checkin.username}</p>
    </div>
  )
 });
}
```